# Can I render static html content in React without injecting styles?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm currently builidng a service that lets users create email templates. Users can preview the templates in the UI. The html for the preview is rendered on the server and send to the client. I currently render the "escaped" and "sanitized" content like this:

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: digestPreview }} />
```

The problem with this approach is that the templates contain `style` tags like: `<style>h1 {color: red}</style>`.

This style will be injected into the rest of the page and messes up the rendering of all `h1` tags on the screen. Not just the ones within the `div` that has the `innerHTML` prop set.

I'm looking for a way to render the html without injecting the styles. I don't want to convert all my styles to inline css.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `<iframe>`.

An example:

```js
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const iframeRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const iframeDoc = iframeRef.current.contentWindow.document;
    iframeDoc.open("text/html", "replace");
    iframeDoc.write(
      "<style>h1 { color: red }</style><h1>Header inside iframe</h1>"
    );
    iframeDoc.close();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Styled H1 in the app</h1>
      <iframe ref={iframeRef} src="about:blank" title="myIframe" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Full available here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-drake-000u0x?file=/src/App.js.

Another way is to use [Shadow DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components/Using_shadow_DOM).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can apply a filter on the `digestPreview` to remove the styles before passing the markup down.

```js
const htmlString = `
<body>
<style>
h1 {color: red;}
</style>
<h1>hello</h1>
<p>
<style>
h1 {color: red;}
</style>
world
</p>
</body>
`;

function toStylelessDocument(htmlString) {
  const doc = (new DOMParser()).parseFromString(htmlString, "text/html");

  var treeWalker = document.createTreeWalker(
    doc,
    NodeFilter.SHOW_ELEMENT, {
      acceptNode: function(node) {
        if (node.tagName === 'STYLE') {
          return NodeFilter.FILTER_ACCEPT;
        }
      }
    },
    false
  );


  let currentNode = treeWalker.currentNode;
  const styles = [];
  while (currentNode) {
    if (currentNode.tagName === "STYLE") {
      styles.push(currentNode)
    }
    currentNode = treeWalker.nextNode();
  }
  for (let style of styles) {
    style.parentElement.removeChild(style);
  }
  return doc;
}

d = toStylelessDocument(htmlString);
console.log(d.body.innerHTML);
```

You can use the `toStylelessDocument` function create an HTMLDocument with the `style` elements removed from the `DOMtree`.

```
const stylelessDocument = toStylelessDocument(digestPreview);

<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: stylelessDocument.body.innerHTML }} />
```